# How to get latitude and longitude from windows 8 phone if app goes into background using cordova 2.3.0

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, background, latitude-longitude

How to get latitude and longitude from windows 8 phone if app goes into background using cordova 2.3.0, I need to get latitude and longitude every 30 min either app is foreground or background.I have done in android, Can we do?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following plugin:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: Is this plugin suport to cordova 2.3.0 for windows 8 phone?.

Comment: Plugin supports plugman so I guess Cordova 2.3.0 is too old for this plugin. I believe plugman support is added from 3.5 and higher. Consider doing a upgrade of Cordova and your app. Since Cordova is on version 5.0 already and a lot has been changed and improved since. And regarding WinPhone 8: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#supported-platforms

Comment: Windows 8 phone: I have updated cordova, Now i used cordova 3.7.1 and i also have added your plugin using command "cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode@0.6.3", I invoked cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable() on device ready event.but i can't call myLocation function if apps go in background(If user press hardware window button),Can we call this function every half an hour if apps not open or apps in background using windows 8 or 8.1 phone .

Comment: I haven't done anything with this plugin on Win phone 8, but if I read the complete documentation I see next: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#known-issues

Comment: Known issue:Plug-in is broken on Windows Phone 8.1 platform, but it's also not working on windows 8 phone, Do you have any solution for both windows 8 and 8.1 phone?.

Comment: Mark, Have you any solution? I need to fixed ASAP it for windows 8 phone.

Comment: Only solution I know of is the solution provided with the katzer plugin for background mode.